# How do I configure redis to allow me to connect through a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, socks, redis

I've got a redis server running on my remote machine. It's currently set only to bind 127.0.0.1.

I can ssh into the machine with ssh -D 9999 mydomainwhatever.net to open a SOCKS proxy and then configure my Operating systems's network preferences to use that proxy for all connections.

Is is possible to then connect to the redis server running on the remote machine with a redis-cli running on my local machine? I'm attempting to use redis-py as the client actually but it's not relevant I think.

I'd prefer not to expose redis to the internet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this answer I assume that default redis port (6379) is used.
You might create a tunnel via ssh so localhost->6379 will point to mydomainwhatever.net:6379 using this command:

```
ssh -L 6379:localhost:6379 user@mydomainwhatever.net
```

Then you might connect to localhost:6379 using redis client.